# how to get select query result from subclasses in hibernate using @MappedSuperclass

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have One Super Class Content

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class Content {

    @Id
     @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    int code;
    String name;
getter and setter
}
```

and two  Entity subclasses Game and Video
Game and Video both are extends Content Class

```
@Entity
public class Game extends Content{
    Game(){ 
    }
}
```

and Video class

```
@Entity
public class Video extends Content{
    Video(){
    }
}
```

Tables Game and video has the same schema as Content class

And main class is

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Session session  = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    Content c  =  new Game();
    Criteria cr = session.createCriteria(Content.class);
    session.createCriteria(Content.class).list();
}
```

i want to get the content from subclass that is from game and wallpaper table 
if i make object of Content class with game class than i want  database result from game table
and if i make object of Content class with Video class than i want  database result of video table

Is there any way to make one method  to get Data From database  from all sub-classes using one get method